# Is it possible to change permission of group by VI editor

Tags: permissions, vi, midnight-commander

I'm new to vi-editor and trying to edit permission of mc (Midnight Commander) group by vi-editor.
I try to locate where is mc:

```
vi /usr/share/mc
```

but it gives me empty file and says mc is a directory..

where i went wrong? 
or it is impossible to change group permission with vi-editor (did it with chmod)?

Answer (score 1):

An editor can't change any permissions and it should not - that is not his job!
But you can change the permissions by using "chmod" command [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606646/how-to-change-file-permission-from-within-vi) from vi-editor:

> Just use
>
> :!chmod +w %
>
> in command mode. % will be replaced by the current file name.